# in windows server 2012 - is it possible to use File Server Resource Manager to screen folders by name?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

In windows server 2012 I can use File Server Resource Manager to screen file types by name and block them being created, ie, block all *.mp3 files being created.

Is there any way to do the same thing for folders? ie, prevent users being able to create a folder with a specific name, such as ".svn"

Users sometimes copy the .svn folders out to the server on accident and it would be nice to be able to block this instead of resorting to deleting them after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File Screens won't do what you're looking for, unfortunately. They apply to files only. You can create a File Screen with the name `.svn` and it *will* prevent users from creating files named `.svn` but folders with that name can still be created.

(This was my initial thought but, to be sure, I just tested it under Windows Server 2012 R2.)

Comment: yeah, I tried multiple variants under file screen but nothing seemed to prevent folder creation. I haven't given up yet but I have a feeling I'm going to have to resort to the scheduled job to purge them.

Comment: well, I'm going to admit defeat on this one - it doesn't seem to be possible using File Server Resource Manager or anything else baked in on windows 2012. I'm certainly not going to write my own file system filter driver ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297595/how-could-i-prevent-a-folder-from-being-created-using-a-windows-service ) so I'm going to mark this as the answer